# Recursively move files to relative subfolder

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, batch

I've looked around for topics about this but I fail to achieve want I need.
Any solution, either in Ubuntu or in Windows `cmd` would be greatly appreciated.

The current structure is

```
/folderA/*.txt
```

with about 100 folders on level `A` and about 50 `.txt` files per folder.
The structure it needs to become:

```
/folderA/proj/*.txt
```

I need to recursively move all txt files one level deeper to a new subfolder called `proj`.

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote & select my answer if you like it :). It really means a lot ;)

Comment: So, you have folders within `folderA`, and they also contain `.txt` files.  Are there folders within folders? and, so, do you want a `proj` subfolder created within _each one_ of them?  Do any subfolders called `proj` already exist?  Are there any non-`.txt` files (that need to stay where they are)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the following script. 
Here's what your existing directory structure looks like 
There are about a 100 folders with 50 .txt files in each.

Try the following script on a test data with a folder structure analogous to what you have before using it for real.

**proj.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /D %%G IN (fold*) DO (
MKDIR "%cd%\%%G\proj"
MOVE "%cd%\%%G\*.txt" "%cd%\%%G\proj"
)
```

Comment: Why don't you move the files directly to the right directory with `move %cd%%%G\*.txt %cd%%%G\proj`?

Comment: I overlooked move's wildcard support. Will modify the answer. Thanks @Lambert

Answer (score 0):

This should do it in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s dotglob
find * -prune -type d | while read d; do 
     mkdir "$d"/proj
     mv "$d"/*.txt "$d"/proj
done
```

If you must use Windows, then try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /D %%G IN (*) DO (
    MKDIR "%%G"\proj
    MOVE "%%G"\*.txt "%%G"\proj > nul
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move files and folders to `/folderB/proj/*.txt`. Remove `folderA`. Rename `folderB` to `folderA`.

Comment: Please clarify.  Should `/folderA/foo/bar.txt` be moved to `/folderB/proj/bar.txt`?  Or should the subdirectory `/folderA/foo` be moved to `/folderB/proj/foo`, with the result that `/folderA/foo/bar.txt` is relocated to `/folderB/proj/foo/bar.txt`?  It's wrong either way.  If you can figure out how to move `/folderA/foo/bar.txt` to `/folderB/foo/proj/bar.txt`, you might have the beginnings of a usable answer — but can you explain why you can't do it all within `/folderA`?